How can I reset the fido PIN on a yubikey using ykman?
In order to test something, I need to set a PIN on a yubikey. I found that I can do that using ykman fido access change-pin. However, I did not find any option to remove that PIN afterwards. I only want to set the PIN for a short test, so how can I remove it again?
I do not want a factory reset. I only want to reset the fido PIN.

As far as I'm aware, the CTAP protocol which governs FIDO behavior does not define such behavior, so you have to do a complete reset of the FIDO applications to reset the PIN.
ykman fido reset

CTAP 2.1 does specify a set minimum PIN length feature which allows you to set a flag requiring the PIN to be changed on the next use, but I have not yet encountered a Yubikey with that feature present.

Update
According to a press release that was released today, the new Yubikey firmware does support the aforementioned CTAP 2.1 features. This however still doesn't change the fact that a key's PIN cannot be reset without resetting the FIDO applications and credentials.

Is there a way to backup and restore the stored credentials?

There is not. It would invalidate the entire security proposition of the key.

So setting a PIN is effectively deleting all credentials? That is… strange.

You can't create any credentials without setting a PIN. Then after your set the PIN, you can create credentials and you can change the PIN without deleting any credentials. What you cannot do is reset the PIN to an uninitialized state while maintaining the credentials.
